# jQuery Mobile: changepage jumpy on slow Android 4.1's devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

On fast Ipad and fast Lenovos the transition is perfect, but on slow devices like "Genesis Tablet" and other small Phones running Android 4.1 I have tested, happens as follows:

When I change from page A to page B, page B is displayed, then it shows Page A for a second, then page B is displayed as expected.

Is it a problem leated to my code logic, or to is it a devide problem, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

What transitions did you use on your pages? As far as I know, jQuery Mobile uses some CSS3 for page transitions, and some of these are not supported by lower versions of Android.

For example if you use a custom slide effect on your page, on Android 4.x.x (or iOS version that supports css3) it will slide, but on Android 2.x.x the page will only fadeIn and fadeOut.

You can read more of the transitions here:
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/transitions/

it is noted that:

> Important: Some platforms currently have issues with transitions. We are working on a solution to solve the problem for everyone. If you are experiencing flickers and flashes during or at the end of a transition we suggest the following workaround. Please note that this workaround should be thoroughly tested on the target platform before deployment. This workaround is known to cause performance issues and browser crashes on some platforms, especially Android. Add the following code to your custom css.
>   .ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
>
> Only seeing fade transitions? To view all transition types, you must be on a browser that supports 3D transforms. By default, devices that lack 3D support (such as Android 2.x) will fallback to "fade" for all transition types. This behavior is configurable (see below).
>
> Transitions were originally inspired by jQtouch They've since been rebuilt, but props to David Kaneda and Jonathan Stark for the initial guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my y Genesis Tablet runs Android 4.1....(Candy crush runs just perfect)....My JQM APp runs under Phone Gap Latest, JQM 3.1.0 and JQ 1.7, it's damn slow...I hope the JQ team work on improving speed...Thanks